# Multiple validation requirements in MVC5

Tags: c#, html, validation, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this form class 'Value' which is used multiple times, the 'Maximum' field is only used in certain instances. I need to validate that 'Maximum' has a value if the 'Show' property is true AND the 'Maximum' field is displayed. Thanks in advance!

Model:

```
public class Value
{
    public bool Show { get; set; }
    public bool Required { get; set; }
    [RequiredIf("Show", Domain.Comparison.IsEqualTo, true, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.ErrorMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "AuthorLabelIsRequired")]
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [RequiredIf("Show", Domain.Comparison.IsEqualTo, true, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.ErrorMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "AuthorLabelIsRequired")]
    public int? Maximum { get; set; }
}
```

HTML:

```
<tr>
                    <td>@Html.EnumString(Model.Data.DateSection.Key)</td>
                    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Data.DateSection.Value.Show)</td>
                    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Data.DateSection.Value.Required)</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Data.DateSection.Value.Label, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Data.DateSection.Value.Label)
                    </td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Data.DateSection.Value.Description, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.EnumString(Model.Data.DescriptionSection.Key)</td>
                    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Data.DescriptionSection.Value.Show)</td>
                    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Data.DescriptionSection.Value.Required)</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Data.DescriptionSection.Value.Label, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Data.DescriptionSection.Value.Label)
                    </td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Data.DescriptionSection.Value.Description, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Data.DescriptionSection.Value.Maximum, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Data.DescriptionSection.Value.Maximum)
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: I worked-around this problem by adding `interface ICustomValidation` with method `bool Validate(ModelStateDictionary dict)` and adding a pre-action filter which calls `Validate` on any provided `model` instance. The `Validate` method in each model is responsible for removing (or adding) entries to the `ModelStateDictionary` which ultimately determines if the model is valid or not.

Comment: This is pretty easy to solve using the method described by @Dai (although I don't know if there's a need for a custom pre-action filter, perhaps in older versions there was), but have you tried anything yourself?  The way the "question" is asked makes it sound like you're just asking for someone to write your code for you.

Comment: Well I'm really wondering if it was even possible to have two conditions in a validation statement such as the one above. Quite frankly I'm a newer programmer (2 years) and didn't think the answer would be as complex as Dai made it seem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually a rather elegant way to handle conditional validation in ASP.NET MVC.  Your model would end up looking something like this:

```
public class Value : IValidatableObject {
    public bool Show { get; set; }
    public bool Required { get; set; }
    [RequiredIf("Show", Domain.Comparison.IsEqualTo, true, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.ErrorMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "AuthorLabelIsRequired")]
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [RequiredIf("Show", Domain.Comparison.IsEqualTo, true, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.ErrorMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "AuthorLabelIsRequired")]
    public int? Maximum { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) {
        if (this.Show && !this.Maximum.HasValue) {
            yield return new ValidationResult("You must specify a maximum value");
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how the model:

1. Implements `IValidateableObject`
2. Has a method named `Validate` which returns the type `IEnumerable<ValidationResult>`

During the model binding process this method will automatically be called and if a validation result is returned your `ModelState` will no longer be valid.  So using this familiar code in your controller will make sure you don't take any action unless your custom conditions check out:

```
public class SomeController {
    public ActionResult SomeAction() {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            //Do your stuff!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Justin, your solution worked great. I have one question though, I couldn't seem to find where the string value of the validation result is stored. I need to access it in my controller and set it as an error message. Is that possible?

Comment: If you want to display the error message in your view you can simply use `@Html.ValidationSummary()` which will spit out any model errors (if there are any).  If you really do need to access the error messages on the controller side you can get a list of `ModelError` by using: `var allErrors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);`.  Then you can iterate through those error objects and look at the `ErrorMessage` property to do your magic.